# Loop through databases get the value and put it in a specific place in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with 2 columns. The first column is populated with folder paths and the second column is empty. Inside each folder path is a single database named DB1. I would like to extract 1 value (VALUE) from each database and then put that value next to corresponding database path, in the second column. This is the query I am using

```
Select CODE, VALUE from DB1 where CODE = 2419
```

I know how to populate a `DataGridView` and how to extract 1 value from the database, but with this I don't even know where to begin.

**EDIT**

I've managed to create working loop but don't know how to add those values to corresponding places in datagridview.

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim sendtroopid As String
        sendtroopid = row.Cells("CODE").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim FilePath As String = sendtroopid 'DATABASE PATH
        Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
        " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CODE, VALUE FROM DB1 WHERE CODE = @CODE", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", "2419")
                Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    While (reader.Read())
                        MsgBox(reader("VALUE"))
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
```

**EDIT 2**

With code above I get all values in msgbox. Only thing left is to insert another loop to put all those values (starting with row 0) to datagridview.
If I replace msgbox with

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = (reader("VALUE"))
Next
```

then all rows are populated with only last value (value from last database).

**EDIT 3**
I've changed

```
value = reader.Read()
```

with

```
While (reader.Read())
value = reader("VALUE")
End While
```

Comment: What is going on with this site? Please, leave a comment if my question has something that needs to be corrected. I see a trend of people down voting just to be able to create illusion of some power in their lives, petty.

Comment: I edited your question, trying to make it more understandable. I still don't know exactly what question you are asking. Also, if you have a database called `DB1`, what is the table name? How do you query a database without the table name?

Comment: FYI It's always best to include some code in your original question, or else it is difficult for people to help. Some clarity and better grammar would help as well. Lacking any of these things missing can result in a downvote.

Comment: I know but that's why I explained in my original post what I can and what I can not do. I know how to extract single value from DBF database but I can not figure out loop to populate those values in second column.BTW this is not the first down vote I got but nobody wants to leave a reasons for doing that.

Comment: I am getting an error in last line "value" : Value of type string can not be converted to system.windows.form.datagridview cell.

Comment: Row.cells(1).value instead. I'm on mobile, will update my answer when I get to a pc

Comment: I've updated original post. Thank you so much, there is no way that I could make my code work without your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure how your query works, but assuming it does, I've changed your code.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim sendtroopid As String
    sendtroopid = row.Cells("CODE").Value
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim FilePath As String = sendtroopid 'DATABASE PATH
    Dim value as string = "" ' declare a string variable to hold the result
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & FilePath & _
    " ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV")
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT CODE, VALUE FROM DB1 WHERE CODE = @CODE", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", "2419")
            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                value = reader.Read()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    row.Cells(1) = value ' put it in the datagridview cell
Next
```

Comment: Only thing needed to be changed (If some1 look here for solution) is : value = reader.Read()  to While (reader.Read())
value = reader("VALUE")
End While. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

Fill it as the rows draw..

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As _
     System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles _
      GridView1.RowDataBound

   Dim DGRow As GridViewRow = sender
   If DGRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      Dim TestPath As String = DGRow.Cells(0).Text
      Dim FoundKey As String = GetKeyFromOtherDatabase(TestPath)
      DGRow.Cells(1).Text = FoundKey 
   End If

End Sub

Private Function GetKeyFromOtherDatabase(testpath) As String
    Dim FoundKey As String = "" 
    '   FoundKey = Double something magical...  
    Return FoundKey
End Function
```

Comment: DataControlRowType is not declared, RowDataBound not found and GridViewRow not defined. Sorry I don'tknow how to fix this.