# Compare values in DGV column with database values and add value to new DGV column

Tags: database, vb.net, loops, ms-access, datagridview

So, Access database has two columns 1st is seller name (SELLER) and second is it's code (CODE). Access database is database with all SELLER CODEs.

DGV is populated from other source and consists of some of CODEs from Access database.
DGV has one column with codes.

I would like to create and populate new column (SELLERNAME) in DGV with SELLER names based on DGV codes and Access database CODEs.

I am going to give an example since it's hard for me to explain this better :
DGV : Column 0, 1st value = 0055, in Access database code 0055 corresponds to the name John
so I would like to put name "John" in DGV Column1, 1st value, nest to "0055" and so on

Here is my code so far :

```
 DataGridView1.Columns.Add("SELLERNAME", "SELLERNAME") '1

    Dim cn As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim odr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim strSQL As String
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\SCodes.MDB")

    strSQL = "SELECT SELLER, CODE FROM SCBASE"

    cn.Open()
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSQL, cn)
    odr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Do While odr.Read
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = odr.GetValue(1).ToString()
        Next
    Loop
```

I don't know what to do next after line `For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`.

EDIT :

I think I am close but I need help with one line of code :

```
 Using sqlconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\SCodes.mdb")
        Using sqlcmd = New OleDbCommand("Select SELLER, CODE From SCBASE Where CODE = @CODE ", sqlconn)

            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE ", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value) 'HOW TO ADD THIS LINE IN LOOP BELOW

            sqlconn.Open()
            Dim result = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
            Do While (result.Read())
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = (result("DOBAVLJAC"))
                Next
            Loop
    End Using
    End Using
```

I had no success with a trial and error. I am trying to put this line `sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE ", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)` in loop below but I am getting all sorts of error.

Comment: How is this question significantly different from your earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24563083/2144390) (which was answered and accepted)?

Comment: I guess it's not significantly different, but there I was asking for one value for each database file and here I am asking how to search for an offset value of a CODE entry in same database that is wrapped in a loop.I am not able to adapt that VB code here. I assume that my questions are boring for some1 experienced in programing but paradox here is if I knew the answer I would ask questions. I am sorry, but before I came here I tried a lot of combinations but my knowledge is limited.

Comment: @Gord I have edited my last post. It's working when (i) is replaced with a row number (manually) but can not make it to work with a loop. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are very close. You just need to `.Add` the Parameter outside the loop and then set its `.Value` inside the loop like this

```vb
Using sqlconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=w:\SCodes.mdb")
    sqlconn.Open()
    Using sqlcmd = New OleDbCommand("Select SELLER, CODE From SCBASE Where CODE = ?", sqlconn)
        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255)
        sqlcmd.Prepare()
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            sqlcmd.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            Using result = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
                If result.Read() Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = result("SELLER")
                End If
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: It's working, thanks you so much. I'm gonna have to find some time to learn a little bit about loops, but even with that I wouldn't know how to insert this line sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 255)